# Drupal compress (gzip) files attached to pages. How to turn it off?

Tags: performance, files

Drupal compress (with gzip) on the fly all files attached to pages during sending them to browser.
It takes too much time especially with PDF.

How to turn it off?

Drupal 6

edit:
Drupal do not compress pages on its own (option turned off), but apache does (output coming from php). And I want to stay it that way with exception of application/pdf (also output of php)

Is it possible?

edit2:
I couldn't change apache gzipping settings in .htaccess, but I was planning changing hosting. I've speeded it up a little and problem is gone now.

Comment: Note that the *html* of the page is compressed if you select compression on admin/settings/performance, but I don't think that's what you're saying.

Comment: May be a better question for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 5):

The question here is one of Apache configuration, rather than Drupal.

I'd suggest checking out the [Apache mod_deflate documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html), which contains sample configurations to disable/enable compression in a variety of circumstances.

Comment: You've pointed me in right direction but I could't change this settings on my hosting even in .httaccess. But I've changed hosting ;)